# regex to remove recurring instances of comment tag

Tags: regex

Hello I want to remove all recurring instances of comment tag which occurs in a data.

Data which I am using is mentioned below

```
<!-- <li><a class="topitemlink" href="/About-Us/Career-Centre.aspx">Career Centre</a></li>
<li><img alt="" width="7" height="22" src="/images/common/separator.gif" /></li>-->
<li><a class="topitemlink" href="/ContactUs">Contact Us</a> <!-- <ul class="topcontactusmenu"><li><a href="/ContactUs">Contact Us</a></li><li><a href="/Investor-Relations/Contact-the-IR-Team.aspx">Contact the IR Team</a></li><li><a href="/Media-Centre/Contact-the-Media-Team.aspx">Contact the Media Team</a></li></ul> --></li>
</ul>
</div>
<!--<a href="http://www.bizsmart.com.my/SME-Challenge/Videos" target="new" style="margin:5px; float:left;"><img width="92" height="40" src="/ABMB/media/MyLibrary/Shared/Images/bizSmart_logo.gif" alt="" /></a><a href="/sabahrun" target="new" style="margin:5px; float:left;"><img width="76" height="40" src="/ABMB/media/MyLibrary/Shared/Images/sabah-run2015_top-icon.jpg" alt="" /></a>-->
```

The regex I am using just captures the first instance but I want all instances to be captured.

```
<!--.*\s.*-->
```

Comment: Don't put the comments in the code to begin with?

Comment: Which language are you using ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like so: `<!--.+?-->` (Example [here](https://regex101.com/r/gW8dU0/1)). Make sure that you have the `sg` flag enabled.

The `s` flag would allow the period character to also match new line feeds, thus allowing you to capture comments which span multiple lines.

The `g` flag will apply the pattern globally, that is, to the entire text.

Comment: @Anoop: Are you providing the `sg` flag combination? Without those the expression will not work.

Comment: I am not using php I am using a third party application. When I add regex in this website https://regex101.com/ all the comment section should be highlighted

Comment: @Anoop: You *should* still be able to provide those flags, usually as `<!--.+?-->/sg` or something like that. I would recommend you consult the documentation of your 3rd party application for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the language you're using but for `php` you can use `/<!--.*?-->/s` , i.e.:

```
$html = '<!-- <li><a class="topitemlink" href="/About-Us/Career-Centre.aspx">Career Centre</a></li>
<li><img alt="" width="7" height="22" src="/images/common/separator.gif" /></li>-->
<li><a class="topitemlink" href="/ContactUs">Contact Us</a> <!-- <ul class="topcontactusmenu"><li><a href="/ContactUs">Contact Us</a></li><li><a href="/Investor-Relations/Contact-the-IR-Team.aspx">Contact the IR Team</a></li><li><a href="/Media-Centre/Contact-the-Media-Team.aspx">Contact the Media Team</a></li></ul> --></li>
</ul>
</div>
<!--<a href="http://www.bizsmart.com.my/SME-Challenge/Videos" target="new" style="margin:5px; float:left;"><img width="92" height="40" src="/ABMB/media/MyLibrary/Shared/Images/bizSmart_logo.gif" alt="" /></a><a href="/sabahrun" target="new" style="margin:5px; float:left;"><img width="76" height="40" src="/ABMB/media/MyLibrary/Shared/Images/sabah-run2015_top-icon.jpg" alt="" /></a>-->';
$html = preg_replace('/<!--.*?-->/s', '', $html);
echo $html;

/*<li><a class="topitemlink" href="/ContactUs">Contact Us</a> </li>
</ul>
</div>*/
```

---

**DEMO:**

https://ideone.com/It6HvW

---

**EXPLANATION:**

```
<!--.*?-->

Options: Case sensitive; Exact spacing; Dot matches line breaks; ^$ don’t match at line breaks; Greedy quantifiers; Regex syntax only

Match the character string “<!--” literally «<!--»
Match any single character «.*?»
   Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
Match the character string “-->” literally «-->»
```

Comment: Its just capturing the second header